# Batch script (recursive file moving) - Stops after moving

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

So I'm not experienced at all with scripting so just trying to figure it out as I go and I'm kinda stuck. So with the following script I'm trying to basically search through a set of folders and within each folder there's two files. They stay paired with each other (for calling an external application to run them together). So I'm having them moved, then trying to call the external application and such. I've also had in to delete the two files after the other application has ran... The issue is that after the 2nd file move, I can't put anything else code wise after it for it to execute. For example, there's two test files I was trying this with. If I add the command to run the external application AFTER the move is performed which is what I'm trying to do....it moves the files but it basically moves the first file twice and uses it as both files if that makes sense. So there's file A and file b. I end up with two file A's, just one of them ends up named file b. If I comment any code after the move, it works perfect.

```
@ECHO ON
SET Loc1Dir=C:\Users\*****\Desktop\temp
SET Loc2Dir=S:\shared\*****\*****\Input\Run\Working_Folder
CD /D  "%Loc1Dir%"
FOR /R %%F IN ("*.STMT*") DO CALL :CopyFile %%~F
FOR /R %%I IN ("*.CARD*") DO CALL :CopyFile2 %%~I

:CopyFile
SET copyfname=%~1
SET fname=driver
ECHO F | XCOPY  /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname%"
:::CALL :CopyFile2
:::GOTO :EOF

:CopyFile2
SET copyfname2=%~1
SET fname2=card
ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname2%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname2%"
```

I know some is commented out, but that's just from moving stuff around and trying to get it to work correctly. Essentially after the 2 moves are done, I will call an external application, and then it will run and then come back and I'll have this script delete the files and then proceed with the next folder/set of files.

Comment: Put `goto :EOF` before `:CopyFile`, otherwise execution falls into that section after having finished the 2nd `for /R` loop...

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with how you are returning after your CALL statements. Using EXIT /R or a GOTO :EOF at the end of the subroutine will return you to where the CALL was made.

I would try something like this:

EDIT: fixed EXIT /R to be EXIT /B

EDIT2: Added EXE in second SUB

````
```
@ECHO ON
SET Loc1Dir=C:\Users\*****\Desktop\temp
SET Loc2Dir=S:\shared\*****\*****\Input\Run\Working_Folder
CD /D  "%Loc1Dir%"
FOR /R %%F IN ("*.STMT*") DO CALL :CopyFile %%~F
FOR /R %%I IN ("*.CARD*") DO CALL :CopyFile2 %%~I

:CopyFile
SET copyfname=%~1
SET fname=driver
ECHO F | XCOPY  /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname%"
foo.exe -argument
EXIT /B

:CopyFile2
SET copyfname2=%~1
SET fname2=card
ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname2%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname2%"
EXIT /B

:EOF
```
````

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. If I add the external call at the end of that, how do I make it recursive? So that it would keep performing it until it’s gone through all of the folders that were in the original directory?

Comment: What is `exit /R`? do you mean `exit /B`?

Comment: Calling an external script or exe can be a bit tricky since you don't nessesarily get a return code, so it could wonk up your processing. If it's an EXE, you can just execute it in the script vs a CALL. If it's a script, I would recreate it as another sub.

Comment: It is an EXE that I'm calling so the issue with it now is that basically with that script it does the moving just fine but it repeats the moving over and over (correct per that code.) Just trying to figure out how/where to put the EXE call in at. The EXE needs to be called after each 2nd file is moved ie. move stmt, move card, exe call. And just repeat.

Comment: Instead of a call, just put the exe and any arguments after the second copy, I edited my answer to illustrate.